# Is there a way to create calculated column in sharePoint based on an excel export list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

I have created a SharePoint list based on an excel list and now I'm trying to create a calculated column using one of the columns that was imported, but it seems that it's not possible. The imported column is a Date column, I have tried with a simple formula like:
= Column1-5 but I'm getting the following error:

*Sorry, something went wrong The formula refers to a column that does not exist.  Check the formula for spelling mistakes or change the non-existing column to an existing column.*

When I'm creating a Date column in the sharePoint list it works fine, but if the column is imported from Excel it's not working and gives me the error above.

Is there a work around for this?

Comment: Edit your question and provide more detail: What are the input columns for the calculation? what are the data types of the input columns? Some column types cannot be referenced in calculated columns.

Comment: Hi @teylyn I have now updated my question! Best regards.

Comment: Edit your question and provide details about your problem. If your problem is about the column names, then show us what the column names are in SharePoint. Not what you wrote in Excel, but what you see in SharePoint. Open the column definition page and post a screenshot where we can see the column Display name AND the URL of the page.

Comment: Also, you haven't given the details I asked for in my first comment, i.e. the data types of the SharePoint columns that show the problem. It's hard to help if you don't provide the information needed to help. We cannot see your screen or read your thought, so you really need to be very generous and inclusive with your problem description.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the issue and I could not reproduce the error in my end. You can check my operation steps as following.

1.Create a SharePoint list based on an excel file.

[image]

2.Create a calculated column by using one of the date columns that was imported.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I’m checking how the things are going on about this issue. Whether the answer helps you? If there is any problem with this issue, feel free to let me know.